# Custom number formatting to display 0000.00

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a database with all the U.S. tariff codes that I need to format.

The numbers appear as: 

   `010129`

Whereas I need them to appear as: 

`0101.29`

I have tried to use custom formatting to match the decimals with `####.??` but it does not work.

The database contains 19,423 rows of data; therefore, if there is a better way to format the numbers using VBA, I will gladly take that response as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have *Text* rather than *Numbers*, reformatting is not enough.  With your data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(A1,5) & "." & MID(A1,6,3)
```

and copy down.  For example:

[image]

**EDIT#1**

If the **double-quotes** do not appear in the data then use:

```
=LEFT(A1,4) & "." & MID(A1,5,2)
```

See:

[image: two]

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it changed the numbers to look as follows:  010129 to 01012.9. It is so very close. Thank you for your response!

Comment: **Do the double-quotes appear in your data or only the the Post??**

Comment: They appear in the post. Someone provided an edit and fixed it. I'm sorry for that.